# I am doing simple A/B testing of two different user interfaces, and looking to count clicks to accomplish a task in both

Tags: user-interface, web, google-chrome-extension, ab-testing

I am trying to A/B test two different Web UIs for the same task and say one takes x1 amount of time and y1 number of clicks to perform the task while the second takes x2 amount of time and y2 number of clicks. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any simple chrome extensions for counting clicks...

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Looking for extensions is off-topic on StackOverflow. If you want to write an extension find a tutorial or start with the official [intro](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

Comment: @Icy You can post programming questions here. You could create your extension and then ask for someone to check your code here. You just have to write a few lines of code to intercept mouse events. It is not difficult. Maybe you can find code examples on the internet. Extensions are just a bunch of files that you bundle in the suitable format and then load into the browser.